# Point addition and multiplication on Sage

Tags: sage, elliptic-curve

I am trying to compute  rP+r'Q  on Sage where r,r' are positive integers and

P=(38*a + 31 : 69*a + 77 : 1), 
Q=(106*a + 3 : a + 103 : 1)

two points on the elliptic curve E:y^2=x^3-x over GF(107^2).

Now I tried to define P and Q on sage simply as I did here but this gives a syntax error. So how do I define points on Sage?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was rediculously simple. Although sage gives you the points (a: b: c), you have to define your point like (a, b, c). How did I just spend over 1h to find out.